# Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find the TestPlan class! on ubunto

Tags: java, jmeter, ubuntu-16.04

lenovo@lenovo-thinkcentre-mini:~/Documents/apache-jmeter-4.0/bin$ jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l my-test-plan-result.jtl -j my-test-plan-result.log -DTHREADS=500 -DRAMP_UP=60 -DDURATION=300

Creating summariser

Created the tree successfully using test.jmx

Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find the TestPlan class!

Answer (score 0):

Try to open and save again your jmx with "Save Test Plan As" and run again. It may happen when your jmx file does not contain "Test Plan" or sometimes when it is not get saved properly.
If that does not work try to rename the default name of the "Test Plan" to something else like "My Test Plan".

[image]

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I just write jmeter before -n and -t command and then the path of script. It works for me
eg. jmeter -n -t (location of test script)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).